# mysql2 gem not loaded (for manual code, not database adapter) in Rails 3.2.16 (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm running Rails app the application on PostgreSQL but needs to execute some arbitrary MySQL query so I included `gem mysql2` into `Gemfile` and `bundle install` and all that.

The code works great (connected to MySQL database and execute query) on localhost (OS X). But when I deploy to the server (Ubuntu) with RVM, Rails doesn't load the gem and gives me this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Mysql2)
```

which basically means `mysql2` is not loaded. And doing `puts Gem.loaded_specs.keys` in the code confirm this. Strangely when I do `rails console` the `mysql2` gem is loaded just fine.

My suspection is that `mysql2` is one of the gems used by Rails for the database adapters, so if the current database adapter is not set to `mysql2` then Rails conveniently ignore that. But I don't know enough of Rails codebase to verify my suspection.

More spec details:

- Rails 3.2.16
- RVM 1.25.27
- Ubuntu 13.04
- Ruby 2.1.2

The `mysql2` gem is corrected added to the global section of `Gemfile`, not just limiting to development tag.

Part of my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
....
```

Comment: Only to confirm, your gemfile looks like `group :production do
  gem 'mysql'
end`
and do you specified in your config/database.yml?
`production:
  adapter: mysql2`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I use `postgresql` as adapter, not `mysql`. I just want to include the gem (just like any other gem) to use its functionality (i.e connect to MySQL database)

Comment: Please update your question with your gemfile. Have you run bundle install on the server as well?

Comment: Why do you need to use MySQL? In any case, my guess is that Mysql2 is not the constant you're after.

Comment: @AlexLynham: I just need to run some arbitrary mysql script.

Comment: @huy - How did you installed new gems?

Comment: @BroiSatse just the usual one: Add to Gemfile and then `bundle install`.

Comment: @huy - Have you run it in the same gemset your server is running?

Comment: @BroiSatse I do. I use RVM and have a dedicated Capistrano task that handles all this. The reason I'm suspecting it's Rails is because when I run `rails console`, Mysql2 gem is loaded properly.

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: @BroiSatse wow that solve it! Thank you! Do you want to add an answer and I'll accept it?